# Getting search result from elastic4s in scala

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, elastic4s

I have the following code and I am trying to get all the hits from the elasticsearch. If I try to write without the query part it only gives me 10 results when I call .getHits.

```
    val resultFuture = client.execute {
      search in "reports/reportOutput" query{ termQuery("mainReportID", reportId.toString)}
    }.await
```

Another issue is that the query part does not actually work and I get nothing. Here is a structure from my elasticsearch.

```
"hits": {

    "total": 266,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits":[
{
    "_index": "reports",
    "_type": "reportOutput",
    "_id": "AUwjbAuKTetnUx12_a97",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": 
    {
        "displayName": "Classic BMW / MINI",
        "model": "Cooper Clubman",
        "dayInStock": "10",
        "stockNumber": "Q323A",
        "miles": "81093",
        "interiorColorGeneric": "Black",
        "year": "2009",
        "trimLevel": "",
        "mainReportID": "4d9e4fd3-7fdf-41c8-8c29-45c5acaf78b1",
        "modelNumber": "",
        "exteriorColorGeneric": "White",
        "exteriorColor": "Pepper White",
        "vin": "WMWML33509TX35944",
        "make": "MINI",
        "transmission": "A",
        "exteriorColorCode": "850",
        "interiorColor": "Gray/Carbon Black",
        "interiorColorCode": "K8E1"
    }
},
```

Answer (score 1):

You can increase how many results are returned by setting a limit on the request, for example:

```
search in "index" limit 100
```

But the default limit of 10 is not set by elastic4s but by [elasticsearch itself](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-from-size.html) and you cannot change it to return all results by default.